# SQLAlchemy. How to order on many to many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model named `NoteType` with a relationship named `sections`.  The `NoteSection` table is joined to the `NoteType` table through `NoteTypeToSectionMap`.

I want the sections list on the NoteType model to be ordered by the position field on the `NoteTypeToSectionMap` model. The code I have below seems to randomly be ordering the sections.

Does anyone know how to get the ordering to work?

Thanks!

```
class NoteType(ModelAbstract):

  __tablename__ = "noteType"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

    sections = db.relationship("NoteSection",
                secondary=NoteTypeToSectionMap.__table__,
                primaryjoin=id==NoteTypeToSectionMap.__table__.c.noteTypeId,
                secondaryjoin=id==NoteTypeToSectionMap.__table__.c.noteSectionId,
                order_by=NoteTypeToSectionMap.__table__.c.position)
```

-

```
class NoteTypeToSectionMap(ModelAbstract):

    __tablename__ = "noteTypeToSectionMap"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    noteTypeId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("noteType.id"))
    noteSectionId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("noteSection.id"))
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Comment: I hope this helps http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers-contacts-and-friends

Comment: @therealprashant: Does not seem to help.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write the relationship as follows.

```
sections = db.relationship("NoteSection",
            secondary=NoteTypeToSectionMap.__table__,
            order_by=NoteTypeToSectionMap.__table__.c.position)
```